# Trace in an Infinite dimensional space

Tags: traces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

How do we define trace of an infinite dimensional space? How one can compute the trace of an infinite dimensional matrix?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace-class_operator

Comment: Since I'm casting the final vote to close, a word of explanation: MathOverflow is intended for research-level questions, and your question, while natural, would belong better on http://math.stackexchange.com which is intended for a broader range of questions in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Start with

[trace class operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class)

[nuclear operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_operator)